# Please let me know how to update release apk without running the below command in react-native android

Tags: react-native, release-builds

I have tried some changes in android/app/build.gradle file

```
android/app/build.gradle 
file project.ext.react = [ bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 entryFile: "index.js",
 bundleInDebug: true, 
bundleInRelease: true, 
root: "../../", ] 
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

Not updating my code output

Comment: this is my code in android/app/build.gradle file
project.ext.react = [
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleInDebug: true,
    bundleInRelease: true,
    root: "../../",

]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

Comment: Please use [edit] to update your post - code is not really readable as a comment.

Comment: Also, could you mention why you want to do it **without** running that command? Because from what I understand the part of the code you provided is suppose to be the **entry point to bundle your react-native js code** into a stand-alone js to be **included in the APK** you are going to release. That is to mean, people aren't gonna need to connect to internet (unless your js code need to fetch something from your server) to run your app correctly.

Comment: Filburt- am not able to post all code am getting some error during post time

Comment: Without run this command , how can update assets 


react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/